# Creating histogram/statistics/scatterplot by classification tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, landsat, histogram, scatterplot

I'm currently working on a land cover classification with Landsat 8 imagery. I already subjected the imagery to pre-processing (atmospheric and topographic correction) and I mosaiced two images.
Now I want to apply a classification in ArcMap. I understand what I should do, but somehow I cannot mannage to create the statistics/histograms/scatterplots. When I click on the statistics, all values are zero. When I look at the properties of the raster layers on the other hand, I can see the statistics, calculated with the 'calculate statistics' tool. It doesn't create a histogram at all and the scatterplots are just 1 dot in the middle of the screen.
Does somebody know what my problem is and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you have not selected the proper raster layer in the classification toolbar.

Just check the raster layer highlighted in the classification toolbar and verify that the it is the same raster that you wanted to classify.

Answer (score -1):

If your raster is floating point then you will have this problem. So you need them to be in integer, the Math tool Int() will help you with that.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.